# Flatten array with multiple objects with nested objects

Tags: javascript, flatten

this particular desired outcome I'm trying to do is turning out to be a bit more challenging that I had expected for someone who is just starting out programming.

I'm storing the results of an API query in an array variable that looks like this:

```
[{
  balance: 4444,
  playerInfo: {
    age: "18",
    gender: "Male",
    level: "2",
    name: "Joe"
  }
}, {
  balance: 3333,
  playerInfo: {
    age: "45",
    gender: "Male",
    level: "3",
    name: "Angel"
  }
}, {
  balance: 2222,
  playerInfo: {
    age: "20",
    gender: "Female",
    level: "11",
    name: "Luce"
  }
}]
```

My desired outcome is:

```
[{
  balance: 4444,
  level: "2",
  name: "Joe"
}, {
  balance: 3333,
  level: "3",
  name: "Angel"
}, {
  balance: 2222,
  level: "11",
  name: "Luce"
}]
```

I've had some minor progress with flat and flatMap but not entirely sure if its the right way to go for compatibility since the intended target group may be using outdated browsers.

The logic for some other answers are a bit tough for me to grasp atm so would appreciate a few pointers in case

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you think you need `.flatMap()`? Either use `.map()` and built completely new objects or `.forEach()` and modify the existing ones (add `balance`, `level`, delete `playerInfo`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and `Object destructuring`.

```js
let data = [{balance:4444,playerInfo:{age:"18",gender:"Male",level:"2",name:"Joe"}},{balance:3333,playerInfo:{age:"45",gender:"Male",level:"3",name:"Angel"}},{balance:2222,playerInfo:{age:"20",gender:"Female",level:"11",name:"Luce"}}]

const formatData = (data) => {
  return data.map(({balance, playerInfo}) => ({
    balance,
    level: playerInfo.level,
    name: playerInfo.name
  }))
}

console.log(formatData(data))
```

```js
let data = [{balance:4444,playerInfo:{age:"18",gender:"Male",level:"2",name:"Joe"}},{balance:3333,playerInfo:{age:"45",gender:"Male",level:"3",name:"Angel"}},{balance:2222,playerInfo:{age:"20",gender:"Female",level:"11",name:"Luce"}}]

const formatData = (data) => {
  return data.map(({ balance, playerInfo: { level, name }}) => ({
    balance,
    level,
    name
  }))
}

console.log(formatData(data));
```

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use `map` method to transform.

```js
let input = [{
  balance: 4444,
  playerInfo: {
    age: "18",
    gender: "Male",
    level: "2",
    name: "Joe"
  }
}, {
  balance: 3333,
  playerInfo: {
    age: "45",
    gender: "Male",
    level: "3",
    name: "Angel"
  }
}, {
  balance: 2222,
  playerInfo: {
    age: "20",
    gender: "Female",
    level: "11",
    name: "Luce"
  }
}];
let output = input.map(obj => ({
  balance: obj.balance,
  level: obj.playerInfo?.level,
  name: obj.playerInfo?.name,
}));

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something short 'n sweet is this:

```js
let rawData = [{
  balance: 4444,
  playerInfo: {
    age: "18",
    gender: "Male",
    level: "2",
    name: "Joe"
  }
}, {
  balance: 3333,
  playerInfo: {
    age: "45",
    gender: "Male",
    level: "3",
    name: "Angel"
  }
}, {
  balance: 2222,
  playerInfo: {
    age: "20",
    gender: "Female",
    level: "11",
    name: "Luce"
  }
}]

let formattedData =
  rawData.map(({
    balance,
    playerInfo: {
      level,
      name
    }
  }) => ({ balance, level, name }))

console.log(formattedData)
```